# how to set docker image name as a file name it creates while building

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

So i want to set the docker image name as a file it creates.
the stages inside the dockerfile are: set new version for pom.xml, compile, package
all using mvn.
i want to set the docker image name as the artifact the build creates
Example: my-app-1.0.1

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine AS build
ADD . /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app
RUN mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="1.0.1"
RUN mvn compile
RUN mvn package


FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY --from=build /my-app/target/my-app-1.0.1.jar my-app-1.0.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java" "-cp" "my-app-1.0.1.jar" "com.mycompany.app.App"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot set the docker image name from within the build file.

Comment: You cannot set the name but you can add a [LABEL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) on build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Thorbjørn Ravn, Andersen and Max advised I changed my approach.
i set it outside and put it right with the image build command.
Thanks for the help everyone!
[command help](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

look at [`docker build` usage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage)

> You can specify a repository and tag at which to save the new image if the build succeeds:
>
> ```bash
> $ docker build -t shykes/myapp:1.0.2
> ```

Comment: you missed my point, i get the name that i want for the image during the image build process, and i want to set it as it.